# how to calculate specific column value in dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am new to R. I have a data frame INPUT that includes

```
       Date        sulfate
 1   01-05-2014   2.3
 2   02-05-2014   2.19
 3   03-05-2014   1.2
 4   04-05-2014   2.23
 5   05-05-2014   4.15
 6   06-05-2014   3
 7   07-05-2014   4.04
 8   08-05-2014   4.79
 9   09-05-2014   2.05
 10  10-05-2014   7.93
 11  11-05-2014   7.74
 12  12-05-2014   2.63
 13  13-05-2014   3.8
 14  14-05-2014   3.52
 15  15-05-2014   3.7
```

I have to include one more column "rate" such that each rate value is equal to each sulfate value of that row divided by (Total row number +1 - each row number ). My code to do this as:

```
for(i in 1:seq_len(nrow(INPUT))) {
       INPUT["rate"] <- NA
       INPUT$rate <- INPUT$sulfate / (seq_len(nrow(INPUT)) +1 -i)
   }
```

But here I am getting correct rate value for first row only.

Comment: There is a fault to your logic. You don't index the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually as simple as

```
INPUT$rate <- INPUT$sulfate/( nrow(INPUT) + 1 - 1:nrow(INPUT) )
```

There is no need to use a for loop since R operations are all vectorised.

---

If you really wanted to still use a for loop (and it really isn't needed) then you would need to fix several issues with your code.

`seq_len` actually creates a vector for i to iterate over, so there is no need to use `1:seq_len()`, which is redundant and will give you a warning message. I would just use the `1:x` idiom and forget about `seq_len` for now

```
for(i in 1:nrow(INPUT)){ ... }
```

You also need to index your columns inside the for loop, as @bdecaf mentions. For example, the following would assign the column `rate` the same values as `sulfate`

```
for(i in 1:nrow(INPUT)) {
   INPUT$rate[[i]] <- INPUT$sulfate[[i]]
}
```

Lastly, the line `INPUT["rate"] <- NA` is being called for every iteration, essentially wiping the assignments that have been stored in the `rate` column previously. If you were trying to initialise the column with `NA`s then you need to do this before the loop e.g.

```
INPUT$rate <- NA
for(i in 1:nrow(INPUT)) {
    INPUT$rate[[i]] <- INPUT$sulfate[[i]] / ( nrow( INPUT ) + 1 - i )
}
```

The last piece of code would give you the correct output, but using the vectorised one-liner at the top of the answer is both easier to type and runs much faster.

Comment: I have included loop as I need to calculate each rate value for each sulfate value.

Comment: @user3659532 There was an issue with the code I gave you, but now that I have fixed it that is exactly what it does. Try it! Let me know if you need some more explanation.

Comment: I need rate value as my first rate value should be 2.3/(Total number of rows + 1 - first row number ie 1). Similarly, I want to calculate second rate value as 2.19/(Total number of rows + 1 - second row number ie 2). (2.3 is my first sulfate value and 2.19 is my second sulfate value)

Comment: @user3659532 Got you! I had misread the question, sorry. Have a look at the updated code in my answer. Also be aware that you asked for `total number of rows - each row number + 1` in the question but you have asked for `Total number of rows + 1 - first row number` in the comments. There is a difference!